# how to enable the default open,that should be last opened, by the user after page refresh? in angular 6

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

Let say I have a list of items displayed in a page. When I click each item, that will show its child item at its bottom. now my requirement is "how to enable the default open, that should be last opened, by the user after page refresh?".

Comment: Post the code that you have tried!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data may be stored in **yourApp.service.ts**. But page refresh restart page scripts and `yourApp.service.ts` constructor too (and all others objects).

I think you may store the identity of the last item in server side, but better store this value in browser storage for key-value items - localstorage.

In the open item method:

```
localStorage.setItem('lastOpenId', value);
```

And after reload in component constructor:

```
this.activateItemId = localStorage.getItem('lastOpenId')
```